# importing FlowTextView in project

Tags: android

i'm try to import [FlowTextview](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView) library into my android eclipse project but i can't add it as an android library project

Comment: Did you checked it as a library?

Comment: @joao2fast4u yes ! but i can't use it

Comment: Did you add it as a dependency on your main Project?

Comment: @joao2fast4u yes after mark that as a library i add that to my project from properties->android

Comment: @user2549089 Have any errors ?

Comment: @LittleChild see my comment under below answer. thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can try download [the jar](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView#Download) directly. And put it in the libs folder.

I suppose that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have used flow text view in the past. To add it as a dependency,

1. Import it to your work space
2. Go to your Android project, click on **Project** -> **Properties**
3. Click on **Android**.
4. At the bottom, you have the option to add a library to your classpath, click it and add flow text view's project.

*Assuming you are using Eclipse*

Comment: i do these steps and library added as android dependency in my project("Android Dependencies" folder appears in project but the jar file in that folder has not any classes) ! but i cant use that

Comment: is there any way to convert library to jar file ? i use many jar libraries in my project with no problem

Comment: It is really early in t he morning where I am at plus I  have to hop off to college. Will answer later, if it isn't urgent :)

Comment: Here is 6am :)) I am very grateful if you could help me

Comment: when i try to create object of that `FlowTextView tv;` eclipse dose not know import which files

Comment: eh ? Hover over the error and you will see the option to import the class or press `CTRL + SHIFT + O`

Comment: nothing to import ! i think the library dose not added correctly in my project !